# Obtain level set function starting from parametrisation

Tags: curves, surfaces, parametrization

I have the following parametrization of a flower curve:

$\theta \mapsto [(R+r\cos(6\pi\theta))\cos(2\pi \theta), (R+r\cos(6\pi \theta))\sin(2\pi \theta)]$

I'd like to know a level set $\phi(x,y)$ such that $\phi(x,y)=0$ associated to this curve.

Basically, I know that the map above is a parametrisation of my curve $\gamma$. However, I *need a level set description of it*, so I'm looking for a $\phi(x,y)$ such that the level set $\{ \phi =0 \}$ is $\gamma$.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by a level set of a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$? Usually, level sets are defined for scalar functions.

Comment: I edited the question. Basically, I know that $\theta \mapsto [(R+r\cos(6\pi\theta))\cos(2\pi \theta), (R+r\cos(6\pi \theta))\sin(2\pi \theta)]$ is a parametrisation of my curve $\gamma$. However, I need a level set description of it, so I'm looking for a $\phi(x,y)$ such that the level set $\{ \phi =0 \}$ is $\gamma$.@GReyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

$$ \begin{align*} x &= (R + r \cos(6 \pi \theta)) \cos(2 \pi \theta) \\
y &= (R + r \cos(6 \pi \theta)) \sin(2 \pi \theta) \end{align*} $$

And we want an equation involving $x,y,r,R$ but eliminating $r$ and $\theta$. There's no general approach for that, but let's see what we can get from these.

$$ \begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} &= R + r \cos(6\pi\theta) \\
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} &= \cos(2\pi\theta) \\
\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} &= \sin(2\pi\theta) \\
\cos(6\pi \theta) &= \cos^3(2\pi\theta) - 3 \cos(2\pi\theta)\sin^2(2\pi\theta) \\
\cos(6\pi\theta) &= (x^3-3xy^2)(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2} \\
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} &= R + r(x^3-3xy^2)(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}
\end{align*} $$

So one solution is

$$ \phi(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} - r(x^3-3xy^2)(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2} - R $$

$\phi$ could also be multiplied by any function which is never zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very clear!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a computer algebra package and eliminate the system of equations. This gives the following 8th degree polynomial:
$$\Phi(x,y)=-R^2x^6 - 3R^2x^4y^2 - 3R^2x^2y^4 - R^2y^6 + r^2x^6 - 6r^2x^4y^2 + 9r^2x^2y^4 - 2rx^7 + 2rx^5y^2 + 10rx^3y^4 + 6rxy^6 + x^8 + 4x^6y^2 + 6x^4y^4 + 4x^2y^6 + y^8$$

You get this from, for example, eliminating $s$ and $c$ from the system of three equations:
$[x-(R+r(4c^3-3c))c,y-(R+r(4c^3-3c))s,s^2+c^2-1]$
where it was used that:
$$cos(6\pi\theta)=4cos^3(2\pi\theta)-3cos(2\pi\theta)$$
and
$$sin^2(2\pi\theta)+cos^2(2\pi\theta)-1=0$$
and where:
$$c=cos(2\pi\theta)$$
and
$$s=sin(2\pi\theta)$$

Comment: Except this gives the additional solution $(0,0)$.

Comment: Yes, that is a drawback.

Comment: I think one can remove (0,0) from the solution by dividing by $(x^2+y^2)^4$. This will generate a level set that is pretty good to evaluate numerically.

Comment: Typo, should be $(x^2+y^2)^2$